# Passing data from controller to view in scala / play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

i am using play framework with scala .
My problem is passing the data from controller to view.
The error code is :
too many arguments for method apply: (content: C)(implicit writeable: play.api.http.Writeable[C])

```
Ok(html.hello(name,getRelatedTracks(name)),"Track_Json")} 

@(name: String,tracks :Iterator[String],Track_Json:String)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misplaced a parenthesis:

```
Ok(html.hello(name,getRelatedTracks(name),"Track_Json"))} 

@(name: String,tracks :Iterator[String],Track_Json:String)
```